# MySql timestamp - different time after update all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I need update all rows in my `events` table. There is column `event_date` with timestamp datatype.

But if i update each row (`event_date` column) with new date (expample: 2015-12-12 12:00:00) then i have some rows with value 2015-12-12 13:00:00.

Point is - why are some rows correct and some are +1h?

In PHP i am using Nette framework and his DateTime object which extends standart PHP DateTime...

Any ideas, hints why this happends?

EDIT: query looks like this:

```
UPDATE `events` 
SET `event_date`='2016-2-13 12:00:00', `event_date_to`=NULL 
WHERE (`id` = 203)
```

Values in php i am setting like this:

```
$row->event_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $oldRow['event_date']);
```

Problem starts sooner - in this table was dates like 2016-2-13 00:00:00 but after select and echo dates changed to 2016-2-12 23:00:00 - but no all rows... only someones. So i make select:

```
 select events.id, events.event_date, events.event_date_to,
 concat(year(event_date), '-', month(event_date), '-', 
 day(event_date), ' 12:00:00') as new_event_date, 
 IF(events.event_date_to IS NULL,null, concat(year(event_date_to), 
 '-', month(event_date_to), '-', day(event_date_to), ' 12:00:00')) as
 new_event_date_to from events
```

That select give me rows like this:

```
769,2014-04-22 19:30:00,2014-04-22 21:45:00,2014-4-22 12:00:00,2014-4-22 12:00:00
```

It means: id, event_date(real db value), event_date_to(real db value), event_date(new value for insert), event_date_to(new value for insert - can be NULL)

And saved to csv file... This file i am parsing now and in foreach updating each row...

I checked ALL queries and times are OK (12:00:00) so i don't understand and stuck :)

Comment: Unfortunately if you're inserting them all the same way there must be something else going on- I doubt MySQL is adding the hour randomly. Perhaps there is a formatting issue on the insert, or some of the values are actually inserting as 13:00:00? Have you dumped your insert statements exactly (the sql) to compare the values? Could you post some of this sql here, maybe even with a screenshot of how they come across once inserted?

Comment: And how are you updating those? What's the actual query being used

Comment: I suspect you should probably be using a `datetime` data-type rather than `timestamp` - timestamps are generally used to log the last time a record is affected using `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (as of about MySQL 5.1 IIRC)

Comment: Maybe add some snippets. This is a little hard to answer your question

Comment: Data are inserting in one foreach and i was dump all queries and no one has 13:00:00 time

Comment: Could this be an issue with Daylight Savings Time - which TIMESTAMPs are aware of but DATETIME fields are not

Comment: For the off-chance that DST isn't to blame: We had a similar issue once that we traced to different timezones on two webservers (UTC and MET) where the Zone info was lost in translation and treated the same in the DB.

Comment: Your concat stuff is redundant. just do `select date_format(event_date, '%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00')`

Answer (score 2):

Your MySQL timezone is probably dissimilar to that of your code (specified in php.ini).

To test this, try inserting this value into a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column:

`foo_column = NOW()`

Concurrently, insert `$datetime` into a separate column - lets say `$datetime` simply equals the current time: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())`

`bar_column = '$datetime'`

If the values are different - then there you have it. Your database is essentially interpreting time differently to your php.